Double escaped value in a json response
After printing out a raw response(not parsed with nlohmann json) from an API. I get something like this:
{
  "Pages": {
    "Limit": 10,
    "CurrentPage": 1
  },
  "Messages": [
    {
      "Subject": "\"Some subject that is surrounded with escaped quotes and has double escaped escape sequences for example: \\u015b \"",
      "Body": "\"The body is structured in the same way\""
    },
    ...
  ],
  "Resources": {
    "Messages\\Unread": {
      "Url": "..."
    },
    ...
  }
}

After parsing
json data = json::parse(response);
std::cout << data["Messages"][0]["Subject"];

This outputs:
"Some subject with double quotes surrounding it and an single escaped escape sequences: \u015b" 

Why would a response look like that if the end goal is to display real characters not escape sequences. Is there a way to display this without having to manually unescape every value?
I tried to parse again a newly created json string that has the value of the response:
json parsed_subject_json = json::parse(R"(
            { 
                "Body":)" + (std::string)data["Messages"][0]["Body"] + R"(
            })"
        );

And then retrieving the value but this results in the same outcome.

I think \u015 needs to have 4 characters, not 3 to be a valid JSON escape sequence, even if it was valid 0x15 or 15 aren't printable unicode characters

Oh sorry I mistyped it it supposed to be \u015b

You should just be able to parse the inner string as another json without needing to wrap it in an object. For instance, try outputting json::parse(data["Messages"][0]["Subject"].template get<std::string>()).

I was able to "unescape" the json value. Thanks to nneonneo, who suggested parsing again with:
json::parse(data["Messages"][0]["Subject"].template get<std::string>())

I wonder why that didn't work when I tried wraping it as an object.
